# SQL getting values by specific needs

Tags: mysql, sql

so I have a database with many columns for badge holding!
I wanted to select every badge where the badge value = 1 but here's the structure:

```
+--------------------------------+
|username| badge1| badge2| badge3|
+--------------------------------+
|bob     | 0     |1      |1      |
+--------------------------------+
```

How can I use "where" to only get 1's without doing each of them separately like:
*where badge1 = 1*, since I have many badges!
**A way would be appreciated!**

Comment: The "*way*" would be to normalize your data to remove the dependency to add an entire column to your database whenever you have a new "badge". What happens at scale here? What happens when you want to introduce a new set of 5 badges? 10? 100? 1,000? Change your schema to meet the standard of third normal form and this task will become much, *much* simpler. MySQL has a hard limit of 4,096 columns anyway, this should tip you off that the design you have currently is not the right solution.

Comment: this is for discord and I probably wouldn't need that many badges. So there is no way to do it in the way I want? Also thanks for the help!

Comment: "*So there is no way to do it in the way I want*" There *is*, but you'll have a lot of maintenance overhead every time you add a badge. You'll need to not only change the schema to add a column, but also add the column name itself to the query that's accessing this data. You can make it easier on yourself and learn a bit in the process by adhering to third normal form in this case.

Comment: Alr man, I appreciate it. I'll get into making it better! Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

One in either of them.

```
SELECT *
FROM BadgeHoldings
WHERE 1 IN (badge1, badge2, badge3)
```

Comment: Oh alr, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  Select * from table
  Where badge1||badge2|| badge3
  Like '%1%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives just for fun & giggles.

```
SELECT 'in' as method, t.*
FROM BadgeHoldings
WHERE 1 IN (badge1, badge2, badge3);

SELECT 'or =1' as method, t.*
FROM BadgeHoldings t
WHERE (badge1=1 OR badge2=1 OR badge3=1);

SELECT 'or' as method, t.*
FROM BadgeHoldings t
WHERE (badge1 OR badge2 OR badge3);

SELECT 'not and =0' as method, t.*
FROM BadgeHoldings t
WHERE NOT (badge1=0 AND badge2=0 AND badge3=0);

SELECT 'not and not' as method, t.*
FROM BadgeHoldings t
WHERE NOT (NOT badge1 AND NOT badge2 AND NOT badge3);

SELECT 'greatest' as method, t.*
FROM BadgeHoldings t
WHERE 1 = GREATEST(badge1, badge2, badge3);

SELECT 'plus' as method, t.*
FROM BadgeHoldings t
WHERE (badge1 + badge2 + badge3);

SELECT 'bitwise-or' as method, t.*
FROM BadgeHoldings t
WHERE (badge1 | badge2 | badge3);

SELECT 'any 1 union' as method, t.*
FROM BadgeHoldings t
WHERE 1 = ANY (select badge1 union select badge2 union select badge3);

SELECT 'not all 0' as method, t.*
FROM BadgeHoldings t
WHERE NOT(0 = ALL (select badge1 union 
                   select badge2 union
                   select badge3));

SELECT 'concat_ws' as method, t.*
FROM BadgeHoldings t
WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', ' ', badge1, badge2, badge3, ' ') LIKE '% 1 %';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a767f6f735f3b466a1630e1bc5beb81d)*

Comment: well man, I mean congrats on all your methods lmao. Though I changed up the database a bit, now it's way easier! Thanks again, Pce!

Comment: If you find an extra method , then please tell me. This list is just for fun, playing with the sql tools in the mysql box.